# Font and background color in LaTeX

Tags: color, book-design

I am currently trying to write up some math notes in LaTex, and I would like the background to be that 'sand'-colored background that is often used by some publishers of (especially classic) mathematical texts.

My question is ... is there a 'standard' choice for such a sand-like color, perhaps coupled with an appropiate font?

I have tried to change the background color manually in Latex, but I cannot seem to make it match to what I am seeing in the books, the colour just doesn't match, and the font is ugly too.

In short: **is there a standard (set of) choice(s) for colour and font when it comes to "brown" background papers in math texts, and if so, what is it?**

Comment: Have a look on the `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` packages to make coloured background for math content (for example)

Comment: As for the fonts, what packages do you currently use in your preamble (that gives ugly result)?

Answer (score 2):

This does not address the font issue, only the request for background colour.

The `colback` option of `tcolorbox` allows for any background colour, here are just two examples of `tcolorbox` box with `ams align` option.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams align,colback=Tan1,colframe=red!50!black]
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} &= \infty.\\
\int x^2 ~\text{d}x &= \frac13 x^3 + c.
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]